# Does $\frac{x}{n}$ converge uniformly on ℝ?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Does $x, \frac{x}{2}, \frac{x}{3}, \frac{x}{4}, \ldots$ converge uniformly  on ℝ? I think that it does not since $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} x/n = 0$. Then $|\frac{x}{n} - 0| = |\frac{x}{n}| < \varepsilon$ then let 
$N = \frac{x}{\varepsilon}$. Now we see that $N$ depends on both $x$ and $\varepsilon$ so there is convergence at different rates, depending on $x$, which tells us that the convergence is not uniform. Does this sound correct?

Is this an ok approach to use to show that there is no uniform convergence for this function on ℝ?

Comment: $x/n$ does not converge uniformly on $\Bbb{R}$, however it converges uniformly on all compact sets of $\Bbb{R}$. In other words: if you don't tell us what is the domain of your functions, the question is meaningless.

Comment: Is this because it is convergent on the compact set so the convergence implies uniform convergence?

Comment: @Crostul the only point-wise convergence I know of that implies uniform convergence is if a monotone sequence of continuous functions converges on a compact space, it converges uniformly.

Comment: X/n is monotonically decreasing and it converges on the compact set of R, so then it converges uniformly

Comment: If by R you mean $\mathbb{R}$, the set of real numbers, then your mistake is that the reals are not compact.

Comment: Yes I mean ℝ, I know that ℝ is not compact, but we can have a compact subset of ℝ which I stated above for example [0,1]. I am simply interested in knowing if my approach in the problem to show uniform convergence is not possible in ℝ is ok

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{x}{n}$ does not converge uniformly on $\Bbb{R}$.

If it were uniformly convergent, then it would converge to $0$, since pointwise convergence gets you $0$.
However
$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \ \left( \sup_{x \in \Bbb{R}} \ \left| \frac{x}{n} -0\right| \right)= \lim_{n \to + \infty} \ (+ \infty) = + \infty$$
so there is no uniform convergence.

Comment: Did you mean lim n--> +∞ just for clarification

Comment: gotcha thanks that makes sense and seems better than what I had thought to show no uniform convergence. Thank you